# How to install bot in multiple teams without adding it to the directory?

Tags: bots, slack-api

I just finished creating my first slack bot in my dev slack team using the Microsoft bot framework.  Now I would like to add the bot to another team for testing.  My bot is not going to be for public use, just internal to the company.  I tried use the Add to Slack button to add it to the new team but I get an :

> OAuth Error: invalid_team_for_non_distributed_app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

You need to go to settings of your app (https://api.slack.com/apps/ → Your app name → Manage distribution) and activate public distribution of your app.

This will **not** add your app to public directory, so only teams with  link from you can add app to their Slack (ex. by "add to slack" button).

Comment: After making it public, after Authorization bot is giving different problem - The Bot Directory is no longer accepting new submissions. Add your bot to the Bing channel so users will not only be able to find it, but chat with it too

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles on this problem again, this might also happen due to the following reasons:

- You have created your app in a particular workspace, and have not distributed it yet.
- You belong to one or more workspaces, but you're not connected to all of them on your browser.

To fix it without having to activate public distribution, you need to make sure you're logged in to the correct workspace in the browser. Go to https://the_workspace_you_created_the_app.slack.com and log in there as well.

Then you can try connecting to the app again, and it should work.