# Expected behaviour of sign in with slack

Tags: authentication, slack-api

Expected Behavior:
Click Sign in with Slack
Redirect you url https://(slackteam).slack.com/oauth/ and asks to sign in
Click 'Continue'
At Dashboard.

Current Behavior:
Click Sign in with Slack
Redirect you url https://(slackteam4).slack.com/oauth/
ERROR: OAuth Error: invalid_team_for_non_distributed_app

Currently, I have a setup page in my project which I am using as my redirect url.
My add to slack button works fine like getting the code when redirected to this setup page and exchange it for an access token. But sign in with slack doesn't.
I want the sign in with slack to take me to the sign in page where the individual members can log in.

I am new to stackOverflow and this is not formatting properly for me sorry for that. If this doesn't make sense then please comment and I will try to improve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install bot in multiple teams without adding it to the directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45523707/how-to-install-bot-in-multiple-teams-without-adding-it-to-the-directory)

Comment: Please check out this link with the same error message and a solution

Comment: Okay. Thanks so much. I will try the above solution and update here if it works.

Comment: It worked kind of. Should I post the answer here or delete this post altogether? And thanks so much @ErikKalkoken

Comment: Happy to help :) Since the question is a bit different, let me post an answer. So then we can close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because your Slack app has not yet been enabled for distribution, which is a mandatory requirement to use the "sign-in with slack" feature.

To enable your Slack app for distribution go to your Slack app admin page and open the "Manage Distribution" page. There you can activate it.

For a more detailed description check the [official documentation](https://api.slack.com/docs/slack-apps-checklist).

Btw. this will not publish your App on the Slack App directory, but it is one of the requirement for doing so.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45523707/how-to-install-bot-in-multiple-teams-without-adding-it-to-the-directory) similar question.

Comment: Thanks so much for providing the explanation as well as to why the error was occurring and that for the Sign in to Slack button enabling it is mandatory to enable distribution. Also, it worked as I wanted it to so again Thanks a ton.